# Merging git hub repository with perforce depot

Tags: github, perforce, git-p4

I have project A. The project A is in perforce as well as in github( Business decision). They are both out of sync. I see that I can use git-p4 tool http://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4 to submit git changes to perforce. Problem is  first instruction of it says is:

git p4 clone //depot/path/project

This command will create a new repo in git hub. I do not want that. I want my existing perforce depot to connect to exiting github repo and then sync files from github to perforce. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. `git p4` is basically just a wrapper around Perforce. It reads changes to a Git repo and issues the proper Perforce commands to commit them (and vice-versa -- it reads changes to a Perforce checkout and issues the proper Git commands to update a Git repo accordingly). So you need to have a Perforce checkout *and* a local Git repo that can talk to that Perforce checkout.

Comment: thank you mipadi. But if I have one local Git repo for both git p4 and git, it would work rt?

Comment: @user2452057: Yeah. git-p4 is just a thin wrapper around some Perforce commands that allow you to use git with Perforce, so you can just use all of your git tools on the same repo that was cloned with git-p4.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you have two different histories for the same project, so you need to find some way to reconcile them.

git-p4 can sync from Perforce (create a new git repository), then you can add a new remote pointing to github, and sync the branches from there.

However that doesn't help with the problem of merging the histories.

You can either:

1. Go with Perforce, and rewrite github history
2. Go with Github history, and get your perforce admin/Perforce (company) to rewrite your Perforce history.

2 is probably (politically) impossible. May be impossible technically. Perforce is designed to prevent history from being altered.

1 will break anyone cloned from your github repository.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at Git Fusion, which is a bridge between Git and Perforce:

http://www.perforce.com/git-fusion

This KB article gives an example of how you may wish to work with a project that is both in Perforce and a public Git repo:

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/7481/

Hope this helps!